# copy the foreign key constraints of one table to another in the same db in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

A table "YO" has its column as foreign key constraints in 4 different tables. Now I created a new table out of YO(create table ...as select) as YO1.

Is there any way to copy all the foreign key constraints into new table YO1 rather than creating the constraints manually one by one. My table uses Innodb engine.

Comment: I don't think so. If you're copying the entire schema you can use `CREATE TABLE table LIKE old_table`, but I don't think there's any way to copy just some part of it.

Comment: The reason that this isn't supported is that such a schema would, pretty much by definition, violate the [principle of orthogonal design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_orthogonal_design).  Don't do it.

Comment: @barmar CREATE TABLE table LIKE old_table will not copy the "YO" table referential constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no quick and easy method for this, however you could query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database to find that information, and with some magic using CONCAT() auto-generate the relevant SQL statements to execute.